# how to mock redis in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, redis, pytest-mock

I want to mock & patch this redis_client in the handler function for unit testing.

````py
def handler(event, context):
    try:
        criteria = event["queryParams"]
        msg = "Search count initiated"
  **redis_client = redis_util.RedisUtil(os.environ.get('redis_host'), int(os.environ.get('redis_port')))**     
        name = criteria.get('name', '')
        name = name.replace('"', "'")```

here redis_util is a local module that contain code mentioned below
````

class RedisUtil:
sqs = None

```
def __init__(self, host, port):
    """
    The AWS SQS Util constructor
    :param host: Redis host
    :param poart: Redis port
    """
    self.redis_db = redis.Redis(host=host, port=port, db=0)

def get_redis(self):
    return self.redis_db
```

```
Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
import redis
import os
r = redis.StrictRedis(host=os.getenv('redis_host'), 
                      port=int(os.getenv('redis_port'))
my_list = r.hget('redis_key', 'redis_pattern')
```